How do I use python to update choice type metadata in sharepoint document with Microsoft Graph API
I have tried to update a sharepoint Document's metadata which is choice type by python using Microsoft Graph API. I have the full control for this sharepoint site and I successed to update other type metadata like string or datetime, but for the choice type, it says the error:
'{"error":{"code":"invalidRequest","message":"Invalid request","innerError":{"date":"2024-12-26T12:56:43","request-id":"a751e55d-fb91-453e-9059-6b00f6edac66","client-request-id":"a751e55d-fb91-453e-9059-6b00f6edac66"}}}'
Could someone can help with that?
Below is my python code
grant_type='password'
tenant_id='tenant_id'

#Use the redirect URL to create a token url
token_url = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token'
token_data = {
 'grant_type': grant_type,
 'client_id': spclientid,
 'client_secret': spclientsecret,
 'resource': 'https://graph.microsoft.com',
 'username':spuser, 
 'password':sppwd
}
token_r = requests.post(token_url, data=token_data)
token = token_r.json().get('access_token')
header={
    'Authorization':'Bearer '+token,
    'Accept':'application/json',
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'X-HTTP-Method': 'MERGE', 
    'If-Match': '*' 
}
site_id='site_id'
library_id='site_id'
url = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/lists/{library_id}/items/66'
body= {"fields":{
               'Tags': ['personal']
           }
}
response = requests.patch(url, headers=header, json=body)


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
